¿Por qué Room no reconoce una de las columnas de una llave primaria compuesta como indexada?
Teniendo la siguiente tabla:
CREATE TABLE `liturgy_saint_join` (
    `liturgyFK` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `saintFK` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`saintFK`) REFERENCES `saint`(`saintID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(`liturgyFK`) REFERENCES `liturgy`(`liturgyID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(`liturgyFK`,`saintFK`)
 );

Estoy definiendo las columnas liturgyFK y saintFK como llave primaria compuesta.
Luego, la entidad la defino de este modo:
@Entity(
    tableName = Constants.LITURGY_SAINT_JOIN,
    primaryKeys = ["liturgyFK", "saintFK"],
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = LiturgyEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("liturgyID"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("liturgyFK"),
        onDelete = CASCADE,
        onUpdate = CASCADE
    ), ForeignKey(
        entity = SaintEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("saintID"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("saintFK"),
        onDelete = CASCADE,
        onUpdate = CASCADE
    )]
)
data class LiturgySaintJoinEntity (
    @ColumnInfo(name = "liturgyFK")
    val liturgyFK:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "saintFK")
    val saintFK:Int
)

Al compilar el código funciona, pero me advierte lo siguiente:

saintFK column references a foreign key but it is not part of an
index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is
modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this
column.

Si defino saintFK así:
@ColumnInfo(name = "saintFK", index = true)
val saintFK:Int 

La advertencia desaparece y el código funciona igualmente bien.
Pero, ¿cuál es el motivo de la advertencia anterior? ¿Acaso Room no reconoce como indexadas todas las columnas que participan de una llave primaria compuesta, como ocurre en las bases de datos? Además, ¿por qué me obliga a poner el index = true solamente a saintFK y no a liturgyFK cuando también ella participa de una relación de llave foránea?
¿Esto es un bug o es una forma extraña en la que trabaja Room? Lo que interpreto es que Room reconoce a liturgyFK como llave primaria de una forma arbitraria.
